# Alternative to Facebook app which can sync contacts with photos in Android device

Tags: gratis, android, facebook

I have Asus Zenfone 2 and I need to sync my contacts with facebook friends. I tried Facebook app. It does the job, but there are many things I don't like about it.

1. It needs much more memory.
2. It has bugs.

I tried to use HaxSync, but it does not supports my requirement any more. So tell an alternative to facebook app that can sync contacts with facebook profile pictures. It should be light weight and bug free.

Comment: May be this Sync.ME or UberSync.

Comment: @Vembu No. Both won't do that

Comment: I'm not using FB, so I cannot give a good answer. But you might check [these apps for Facebook Sync](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_sync#group_65) and see if one of them fits.

Comment: Sync.ME does the job. Great app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Full Contact to help with that:

https://www.fullcontact.com/features/sync-google-contacts/

It doesn't have an Android app (yet), but you could use it to sync your Facebook contacts with your Google Contacts and, by doing that, your contacts on your Android smartphone would be synced with the photos and other data from Facebook.  Twitter and Linked-in work as well.

Full Contact can search for photos of your contacts in multiple social networks sites and add much more information.

Comment: How to sync Facebook contacts with this application ?

Comment: You have to sign up for an account with Full Contact (using your Gmail account) and after your Gmail contacts got synchronized you also should connect your Facebook account with Full Contact. 

After the Facebook sync, FullContact will update your Gmail contacts and  the photos of their Facebook profile should appear on your Android phone.  It might take a few hours until everything is synced, depending on how much contacts you have.

Comment: How to connect my Facebook account to Full Contact ? I can't find any option to do it.

Comment: You should do that on FullContact's website. On the left sidebar, under "All Contacts" you'll find an option "Add Address Book". After clicking on that option, you will be presented with a list of social websites and Facebook will be there among the options. Just click on Facebook's icon, authorize FullContact to access your Facebook account and wait for the synchronization.

Comment: is it possible to update my google contacts with the unified information from fullcontact? I've managed to get it to sync with my contacts, pulled in twitter and facebook stuff, but i have to use fullcontact to access it, can't access the information through google contacts.